# If $d$ is a metric then $\frac{d}{1+d}$ is a metric. What are the applications of this? Where does it come up?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

[If $d(x,y)$ is a metric, then $\frac{d(x,y)}{1 + d(x,y)}$ is also a metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309198/if-dx-y-is-a-metric-then-fracdx-y1-dx-y-is-also-a-metric)

This is a question that if $d(x,y)$ is a metric, then $\frac{d(x,y)}{d(x,y)+1}$ is a metric.

Is this true for other functions of $d$ and what are the applications of this property?

Comment: If $d$ is the usual Euclidean metric, then this new metric has all points contained in the unit ball:  If $x = 0$, then the limit of the new metric, as $y$ gets further from the origin, is $1$.

Comment: Sometimes we need a metric that is bounded by a constant we can control. Particularly when we (when dealing with series and such) need to add infinitely many metrics together.

Comment: **[1]** Defining a metric on a countable Cartesian product of metric spaces in a way that is topologically equivalent to the usual product topology on the product of the corresponding topological spaces -- see [Show that the countable product of metric spaces is metrizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/361778/13130). **[2]** Defining a metric for complex-analytic functions on an open set in a way to give uniform convergence on compact sets -- see [Proving that a metric on space of analytic functions is equivalent to compact convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/592206/13130)

Comment: here are many other functions of $d$ that also provide metrics, and more importantly, as here, metrics that are equivalent to $d$. That is, a set will be open under the new metric if and only if it is open under $d$. Another example of how you can replace an unbounded metric with an equivalent bounded metric is just $d′=\min\{d,1\}$.